# Programatically Add users to group in AzureAD as group owner

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there an API for AzureAD which allows group owners to add users to their owned groups?

Using the Graph api's looks to require admin consent (granting admin permissions) and so provides access to more than the user's owned groups. I don't want to grant this.

I also don't want to use delegated access - an admin shouldn't need to be present for a group owner (perhaps a service principal?) to add users to their own group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some interesting findings.

A) If you set a service principal as the owner of a group, and want to manage the group with the service principal, you have to add and grant necessary permission for Azure AD Graph API.

B) If you set a user as the owner of a group, then you can use the public client (1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894) and user credential to acquire token, and then call the AAD graph API as the user to manage the group.

Here, I use PowerShell to make http requests. You can use other program languages.

```
# Get token for Azure AD Graph  
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_name_or_id, for example: hanxia.onmicrosoft.com}/oauth2/token"
$body = @{grant_type='password';resource='https://graph.windows.net';client_id='1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894';username='normaluser@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com';password='a*******7'}
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body
$accessToken = $result.access_token

# Azure AD Graph. Get group information
$tenantId = "e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb"
$groupId = "f37d06f2-e26f-45f9-b9b1-da13d0b79ea7"
$apiVersion = "1.6"

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get `
                    -Uri ("https://graph.windows.net/" + $tenantId + "/groups/" + $groupId +"?api-version=" + $apiVersion) `
                    -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $accessToken }
$result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json

# Azure AD Graph. Get users in group
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get `
                    -Uri ("https://graph.windows.net/" + $tenantId + "/groups/" + $groupId +"/`$links/members" +"?api-version=" + $apiVersion) `
                    -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $accessToken }
$result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json

# Azure AD Graph. Add user to group
$userObject = @{"url" = "https://graph.windows.net/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/directoryObjects/3f43b292-adac-48f9-a623-ee76ca9c7174"} | ConvertTo-Json
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post `
                            -Uri ("https://graph.windows.net/" + $tenantId + "/groups/" + $groupId +"/`$links/members" +"?api-version=" + $apiVersion) `
                            -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $accessToken; "Content-Type" = "application/json" } `
                            -Body $userObject
if($result.StatusCode -eq 204){ Write-Host "User added" }
```

Note:

1. **1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894** is a common application from Microsoft for every tenant.
2. API Reference: [Operations on groups | AAD Graph API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations)

Answer (score -1):

The reason that consent is needed is that while the group owner has rights to add users to a group, an app by default does not. The delegated permissions give the app rights to modify groups on behalf of the user, depending on the user's rights as well. It's usually the better approach. App permissions give the app itself permissions to act without a user. Which is often too much, but has its use cases.

You need to grant the delegated permission at least to the app so it can do the modification on behalf of the user.

Comment: I have made the app an owner of the group. There are no users involved.

The app should be able to do this without any other admin?

Comment: Ahh okay, sorry I seem to have misread your question. Your app still needs to be assigned permissions to call Graph API though.

Comment: Also, forgetting the service principal aspect of this... a user can add other users to a group it owns through https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/groups - how can this be done programatically? e.g. what rest api call or powershell could the user run to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Right, and the only way to grant access to the graph api is to grant access to everything in the directory. So I don't want to do that... since there's UI for users to do this, is there not another api somewhere?

Comment: Nope, you need to call MS Graph API. And it kinda sounds like you need app permissions :/ Which I agree isn't perfect since it gives the app tenant-wide access

Comment: Jack Jia has a great solution in the other answer. Turns out there's a built in app in all directories to do this against the graph api.

Need a real user, not app registration, but I can deal with that.